# Set camera focus on particular marker on Google map on itemclick

Tags: android, json, google-maps, listview

With the help of this [Tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html)
 I made `onItemClickListner` class

```
public class OnItemClickListenerListViewItem implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    Context context = view.getContext();



    TextView textViewItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem));



    // get the clicked item name

    String listItemText = textViewItem.getText().toString();



    // get the clicked item ID

    String listItemId = textViewItem.getTag().toString();



    // Toast not showing Item name  

    Toast.makeText(context, "Item: " + listItemText + ", Item ID: " + listItemId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

> Camera focus is not working

```
if (listItemText.equals("ROMYS")) {
        CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                coordinate, 15);
        googleMap.animateCamera(location);
    }
```

I tried this [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007164/set-camera-focus-on-particular-marker-on-google-map-on-listview-item-click) but it does not work

And this is my class code right now [myClassCode Pastbin Link](http://pastebin.com/WGWBMQnX)

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971698/how-to-focus-at-marker-in-google-map-in-android.

Comment: no sir not working !